# SAS Argument 1 to the function PRXMATCH is missing

Tags: regex, sas

When I run prxmatch I keep getting an error saying argument 1 is missing. I've checked the pattern and it processes correctly, but when I try to use it through SAS I get the errors below.

Here is an example `WORD_0012_MUK613` which returns `N`

```
data test2;
set test;
if prxmatch(prxparse('^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$'), external_id) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

> NOTE: Argument 1 to the function PRXMATCH is missing.
>
> ERROR: Argument 1 to the function PRXMATCH must be a positive integer returned by PRXPARSE for a valid pattern.
>
> ERROR: Closing delimiter "^" not found after regular expression "^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$".
>
> ERROR: The regular expression passed to the function PRXPARSE contains a syntax error.

When I add the delimeter it gets rid of the error but still doesn't match

```
data test2;
set test;
if prxmatch(prxparse('/^COAF_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$/'), external_id) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `prxparse` exists to allow you to separate the compilation of the regex from its use.  That's useful for code structure.  However, it's not really useful in the way you used it there - nesting it.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  rx_word = prxparse('^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$');
  if prxmatch(rx_word, external_id) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

Second, you need delimiters in SAS to wrap around the regex (This will be useful in step 3).  Any character is fine - the first character you pass it will become the delimiter, so use something that you won't use anywhere else except as the delimiter.  `/` is common, but I like to use `~` sometimes as `/` can be needed in the regex and would have to be escaped.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  rx_word = prxparse('~^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$~');
  if prxmatch(rx_word, external_id) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

Third, you need some options.  `o` at minimum - that way the regex isn't compiled once per row of your dataset, that's horribly slow.  `i` for case insensitive.  `s` means ignore linebreaks in the string, if that's relevant.  They go after the ending delimiter - hence, the need for them (though they're not optional even if you're using no options).

```
data test2;
  set test;
  rx_word = prxparse('~^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$~o');
  if prxmatch(rx_word, external_id) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

Fourth, SAS strings are full length (non-varchar) strings.  If you have spaces after your string, you'll get no match.  So make sure to trim your strings when you're matching them, if you include the `$` end of string marker and you're not 100% sure your strings aren't exact length (or use `substr` or something else to get that exact length).

```
data test2;
  set test;
  rx_word = prxparse('~^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$~o');
  if prxmatch(rx_word, trim(external_id)) then match = 'Y'; else match = 'N';
run;
```

Finally, you can improve the last statement by using `ifc`, since prxmatch returns 0 for no match.

The full example:

```
data test;
  length external_id $20;
  input external_id $;
  datalines;
WORD_0012_MUK613
WORD_5344_915ABC
;;;;
run;

data test2;
  set test;
  rx_word = prxparse('~^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$~o');
  match = ifc(prxmatch(rx_word, trim(external_id)),'Y','N');
  put match=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for PRXPARSE function plus you need delimiters for the expression example /exp/

```
40         data _null_;
41            x = prxmatch('/^WORD_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$/','WORD_0012_MUK613 | N');
42            put _all_;
43            run;

x=0 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```